# How to add onclick event on a row in grid view (windows form application)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

There is a backround worker, a tableLayoutPanel, and a bunch of gridviews and labels that I add (dynamically - programmaticaly) to the tablelayoutpanel.

The above code works fine, but I need to add an onclick event on the row that will be added to the gridview each time. How can I do this?

```
 var lbltotalcount = tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Find("lbltotalcount_" + GridId, true);
            ((Label)lbltotalcount[0]).Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                ((Label)lbltotalcount[0]).Text = (Convert.ToInt32(((Label)lbltotalcount[0]).Text) + NumOfMatch).ToString();
            });    

            var obj = tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Find("dgv_" + GridId, true);


            ((DataGridView)obj[0]).Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                string[] row = new string[] { Word, txturl.Text, Url, NumOfMatch.ToString() };

                DataGridViewRow dgvRow = new DataGridViewRow();
                DataGridViewCell dgvCell;

                dgvCell = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();                
                dgvCell.Value = Word;
                dgvRow.Cells.Add(dgvCell);                

                dgvCell = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
                dgvCell.Value = txturl.Text;
                dgvRow.Cells.Add(dgvCell);

                dgvCell = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
                dgvCell.Value = Url;
                dgvRow.Cells.Add(dgvCell);

                dgvCell = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
                dgvCell.Value = NumOfMatch.ToString();
                dgvRow.Cells.Add(dgvCell);                                              

                ((DataGridView)obj[0]).Rows.Add(dgvRow);
                ((DataGridView)obj[0]).Refresh();
                ((DataGridView)obj[0]).Update();
            });
```

Comment: you mean tht you want to click a button in that code?

Comment: the row will be fine, and then on the row click I can handle the rest.

Comment: This event needs to be attached dynamicaly each time I add the row.
Then I need to click on the row and fire that event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure that is what you want.. lets try it..

```
  void yourMethod()
 {
  var lbltotalcount = tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Find("lbltotalcount_" + GridId, true);
          ((Label)lbltotalcount[0]).Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            ((Label)lbltotalcount[0]).Text =     (Convert.ToInt32(((Label)lbltotalcount[0]).Text) + NumOfMatch).ToString();
        });    

        var obj = tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Find("dgv_" + GridId, true);

       ((DataGridView)obj[0]).SelectionChanged += new EventHandler(My_SelectionChanged);


        ((DataGridView)obj[0]).Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            string[] row = new string[] { Word, txturl.Text, Url, NumOfMatch.ToString() };

            DataGridViewRow dgvRow = new DataGridViewRow();
            DataGridViewCell dgvCell;

            dgvCell = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();                
            dgvCell.Value = Word;
            dgvRow.Cells.Add(dgvCell);                

            dgvCell = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
            dgvCell.Value = txturl.Text;
            dgvRow.Cells.Add(dgvCell);

            dgvCell = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
            dgvCell.Value = Url;
            dgvRow.Cells.Add(dgvCell);

            dgvCell = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
            dgvCell.Value = NumOfMatch.ToString();
            dgvRow.Cells.Add(dgvCell);                                              

            ((DataGridView)obj[0]).Rows.Add(dgvRow);
            ((DataGridView)obj[0]).Refresh();
            ((DataGridView)obj[0]).Update();
          var index = ((DataGridView) obj[0]).RowCount;
          ((DataGridView) obj[0]).SelectedRows[index - 1].Selected = true;
        });  
  }

   void My_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      // bla bla ...

    }
```

Comment: Yesss! the only problem was that instead of EventHandler in needed DataGridViewCellEventHandler. So it works. Thanx!